Power BI Forecasting: Forecast full data based on partial
I'd like help forecasting completion rate by start date.
People start a programme, after they start, at any time they may finish the programme and when they do they will have a status of Completed or Withdrawn. I have data as far back as 2016 and most people will finish their program within 4 years although it could be alot shorter or alot longer than this.
When I try and forecast in Power BI, Completion Rate, I encounter two issues.

It bases the forecast, in part, on the most recent data which has a low finished %, hence data will be inaccurate.

It doesn't forecast past completion rate based on future finishers.


Anyone know how I can achieve this?
I've thought about having two measures, one for actual finishers (ones I know about) and then adding on a potential forecast based on just those left to finish but not even sure how to display these together.

It's a mess. Try to link a sample of the data anonymized so we can have a look.
